# Resize Navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to resize my navigation bar smaller when the user scrolls. 
This is my url [website](http://www.agl.run-time.co.za)

I have this function inserted : (using a javascript / css / plugin in wordpress)

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
  nav.art-nav{
  background-color:#ccc;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
nav.art-nav.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}
```

I have tried all I can think of to edit the example found at [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Filo/m7yww8oa/) 
to suite my site, but cannot get it to resize, any advice would be appreciated please,

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The JSFiddle example works because that navbar doesn't have a fixed height. Your `.art-nav` does.

I think it will work if you change `min-height: 35px;` to `height: 35px;`.

Comment: Thank you @Bert, but I have tried changing to the above, and it is still not shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the above to

```
.art-nav{
  background-color:#ccc;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}
```

It is now working - I hope this can help others using an Artisteer created theme  :)